# Magnific popup "The image could not be loaded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to make what does when you click on a link, showing a modal window with the generated link to the google maps.
There is my .html

```
 <div class="map-google-link">
      <%= link_to "show map", (event.google_map_url) %>
     </div>
```

There is my .js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.map-google-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'image',
  midClick: true 
});
});
```

how fix?

Comment: How fix?  What wrong?

Comment: plugin is responsible to me “The image could not be loaded”